# Android alternative for Gallery

Tags: android, android-viewpager, image-gallery, horizontal-scrolling

`Gallery` has been deprecated since API 16, and the official Android documentation suggests the usage of either `ViewPager` or `HorizontalScrollView` instead.

I would like to implement a `View` similar to the deprecated `Gallery`, can anyone suggest a source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u can use many library in github . or just create your project and extends your class with `HORIZONTAL`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the new `RecyclerView` widget with a `LinearLayoutManager` and set the orientation to [HORIZONTAL](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html#setOrientation(int))

Comment: can you get more detail about implementation ?